# Redux - does not update although JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I use Redux and have the following state:

```js
const inistialStateRedux = {
  filters: {
    data: {
      countries: [],
      divisions: [],
      companies: [],
      locations: [],
      fields: [],
      associativeFilterMap: {
        bereiche: [],
        gesellschaften: [],
      },
    },
  },
};
export default inistialStateRedux;
```

My actions.js looks like this:

```js
export const SET_CONFIGURED_FILTERS = 'SET_CONFIGURED_FILTERS';
export const SET_CONFIGURED_FILTERS_RESYNC = 'SET_CONFIGURED_FILTERS_RESYNC';
export const setConfiguredFilters = (key, value) => ({
  type: SET_CONFIGURED_FILTERS,
  key,
  value,
});

export const setConfiguredFiltersResync = (key, value) => ({
  type: SET_CONFIGURED_FILTERS_RESYNC,
  key,
  value,
});
```

My helper.js looks like this:

```js
export const createReducer = (initialState, handlers) => (
  state = initialState,
  action
) => {
  if (action.type in handlers) {
    return handlers[action.type](state, action);
  }
  return state;
};

export const multiUse = (reducer, name = '') => (state = null, action) => {
  if (action.name !== name) return state;

  return reducer(state, action);
};
```

My reducer.js looks like this:

```js
import {
  createReducer
} from '../helper';
import * as Action from './actions';

export default createReducer({
  data: {},
}, {
  [Action.SET_CONFIGURED_FILTERS]: (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    data: {
      ...state.data,
      [action.key]: action.value,
    },
  }),
}, {
  [Action.SET_CONFIGURED_FILTERS_RESYNC]: (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    data: {
      ...state.data,
      [action.key]: action.value,
    },
  }),
});
```

What I want to achieve:

**Set a new countries array.**

My code:

```js
  store.dispatch(setConfiguredFiltersResync('countries', configured.countries))
```

Even if I do the following in my reducer:

```js
[action.key]: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(action.value)),
```

*Redux shows: (states are equal).*

What am I doing wrong ? How to fix that ?

Comment: Try to not create deep nested data in your store. This store is good: {companyReducer: { 
var1: [], var2: '', var3: 1231 }}

Comment: Hi, yes I know. But actually this does not answer my question.